# ArcGIS Javascript Identify Task and Deferreds

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis, deferred

I'm trying to use the identify tool on a dynamic map service layer and display an info window that shows images that are attached to the records.  I have to monkey around and get the feature layer, but that works ok.  I'm having an issue with the deferreds.

Here's the problem:the identify task returns a dojo deferred object.  I have a callback I run when the deferred is resolved.  In that callback function, I run another function called queryAttachmentInfos.  When this runs, the line "return feature" will fire before the queryAttachmentInfos function.  I don't know why.  Shouldn't everything in the callback occur synchronously?  How do I make the callback function wait for the queryAttachmentInfo to complete?  I'm using a setTimeout to force the script to wait one second, which works sometimes, but I know that's not a good solution.

Any help would be welcome.

Code below...

```
function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
        identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
        identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

        var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

        deferred.addCallback(function(response) {     

          return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
            var feature = result.feature;
            var fLayerPath = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0"
            var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(fLayerPath);
            var objID = feature.attributes.OBJECTID;
            feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
            //alert(result.layerId);
            if(result.layerName === 'Tax Parcels'){
                featureLayer.queryAttachmentInfos(6737858, function (infos) {
                            if (infos.length>0) {
                                el = document.createElement('img');
                                el.setAttribute('src', infos[0].url);
                                t = document.createElement('table');

                                //first row Request Type
                                r = t.insertRow(0); 
                                r.bgColor="#00FFFF";
                                c = r.insertCell(0);
                                c1 = r.insertCell(1);
                                c.innerHTML="Request Type";
                                c1.innerHTML=feature.attributes.building;

                                //second row District
                                r1 = t.insertRow(-1);
                                c2 = r1.insertCell(0);
                                c2_1 = r1.insertCell(1);
                                c2.innerHTML="District";
                                c2_1.innerHTML=feature.attributes.UNIT;


                                //third row Status
                                r2 = t.insertRow(-1);
                                r2.bgColor="#00FFFF";
                                c3 = r2.insertCell(0);
                                c3_1 = r2.insertCell(1);
                                c3.innerHTML="Status";
                                c3_1.innerHTML=feature.attributes.PARCELID ;

                                var len = infos.length;
                                    for (var i = 0; i < len;i++)
                                    {
                                        newRow = t.insertRow(-1);
                                        newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                                        newCell.colSpan=2;
                                        newCell.innerHTML="<a href="+infos[i].url+"/><img src="+infos[i].url+"/>";
                                        //els[i]= document.createElement('img');
                                        //els[i].setAttribute('src', infos[i].url);

                                        //alert(infos[i].url);

                                    }
                                var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", t);
                                feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                                //return feature;
                            }
                        else
                        {
                            var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "${Postal Address} <br/> Different: ${First Owner Name}");
                            feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
                            //eturn feature;
                        }
                        });
              console.log(feature.attributes.PARCELID);

            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'Building Footprints'){
              var template = new esri.InfoTemplate("", "Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}");
              feature.setInfoTemplate(template);
              //return feature;
            }
            return feature;
          });
        });
        setTimeout(function(){map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ])},1000); 
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
      }
```

Comment: "Shouldn't everything in the callback occur synchronously?" Not necessarily. An asynchronous callback may itself contain asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that `featureLayer.queryAttachmentInfos()` is itself asynchronous so, in the case of 'Tax Parcels', `map.infoWindow.setFeatures()` and `map.infoWindow.show()` can only be called when that asynchronous activity has completed.

Meanwhile, in the case of 'Building Footprints', `map.infoWindow.setFeatures()` and `map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint)` can be called synchronously (within the outer asynch callback).

This means there is a small block of code that should be called from two places. You could repeat several lines of code or write a worker function as follows :

```
var showInfoWindow = function(feature, tpl) {
    // A utility function which creates and populates an infowindow
    // and shows it at evt.mapPoint
    feature.setInfoTemplate( new esri.InfoTemplate("", tpl) );
    map.infoWindow.setFeatures(feature);
    map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
}
```

And here it is in context (with all the bulky DOM building removed for clarity) :

```
function executeIdentifyTask(evt) {
    identifyParams.geometry = evt.mapPoint;
    identifyParams.mapExtent = map.extent;

    var showInfoWindow = function(feature, tpl) {
        // A utility function which creates and populates an infowindow
        // and shows it at evt.mapPoint
        feature.setInfoTemplate( new esri.InfoTemplate("", tpl) );
        map.infoWindow.setFeatures(feature);
        map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
    }

    var deferred = identifyTask.execute(identifyParams);

    deferred.addCallback(function(response) {
        return dojo.map(response, function(result) {
            var feature = result.feature;
            //var objID = feature.attributes.OBJECTID;//???
            feature.attributes.layerName = result.layerName;
            if(result.layerName === 'Tax Parcels') {
                var fLayerPath = "http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/FeatureServer/0";
                var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(fLayerPath);
                featureLayer.queryAttachmentInfos(6737858, function(infos) {
                    var t, tpl;
                    if(infos.length > 0) {
                        t = document.createElement('table');
                        //***** Reinsert several lines of code here *****
                        //***** Remember to localize variables with `var` *****
                        tpl = t;
                    }
                    else {
                        tpl = "${Postal Address} <br/> Different: ${First Owner Name}";
                    }
                    showInfoWindow(feature, tpl);//<<<<< create, populate and display an infowindow
                });
            }
            else if (result.layerName === 'Building Footprints') {
                showInfoWindow(feature, "Parcel ID: ${PARCELID}");//<<<<< create, populate and display an infowindow
            }
            //return feature;//???
        });
    });
}
```

All I've done is to shuffle things around without any particular knowledge of dojo or arcgis. Barring errors on my part, everything *should* work. That said, I have only been able to test for syntax errors so be prepared to do some debugging. And remember to paste the bulky table-building lines back in.

Comment: You are correct, the queryAttachmentInfos is a deferred.  I didn't catch that.  I don't think you're solution would work because the showInfoWindow has to be called outside the callback function.  The identify task can return an array of values (see the "return dojo.map" line).

Comment: I guess I'm dealing with nested deferreds.  The outer one (the deferred.callback) and the inner one (queryAttachmentInfo).  Is there a way to have the outer one wait for the inner one?

Comment: bd, are you saying that you *think* my code doesn't work or that it doesn't work? What happens if you run it? There are no obvious scoping issue that should prevent `showInfoWindow` from working - `feature` and `tpl` are passed to it and everything else (`esri`, `map` and `evt`) should be automatically available unless your original code was incorrect in this regard. As far as I can tell, there would be no advantage to reversing the inner and outer deferreds. If `identifyTask` can return an array of values, then that's another issue, not predictable from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

B-B,
I tried the code and I couldn't get it to work.  It looks like it should work, or at least should display an infowindow on the map.  Stepping through it all the objects it needs to display the window are populated.  Not sure why it doesn't....

I apologize if I wasn't clear in my first post.  One issue is that the identify task can (and usually does) return an array of features.

Every way I look at it, the "map.infoWindow.setFeatures([ deferred ]);" line fires before the queryAttachmentInfo fires.  I have a dumb workaround where I use a window.setTimeout function to wait one second, but that doesn't guarantee all the queryAttachmentInfos will be resolved.